# Explicit formulation of an bijective function that maps $\mathbb{Z}^3$ to $\mathbb{N}_0$ from the point $(0,0,0)$ outwards and it's inverse

Tags: sequences-and-series, coordinate-systems, natural-numbers

I am looking for such a function, that in effect maps the point (0,0,0) to 0 and then the points "surrounding" 0, so (1,0,0),(0,1,1),(0,-1,1)... to 1,2,3,4... in ascending order.
It is not important in which order the surrounding points are "visited", just that all of them are before the next more "distant" layer around the origin.
meaning 0 is mapped to (0,0,0), [1,26] is mapped to all coordinates only containing 1's 0's and -1's, and so on.

What I have tried of course is finding an iterative formulation to iterate over the sides of a cube of the given sidelength, but the reverse is far more difficult and inefficient, and thus I am looking for an elegant mathematical formulation of the problem.
Iterating first over an edge, and then, line by line traveling along the orthogonal to this first edge until we reach it again, then adding the iteration of a cube.

What makes it more difficult: I do not have an upper bound to the coordinates in question.

Do you have any idea how such a formulation could look like, effectively enumerating the outline of a cube explicitly, and turning a coordinate into an enumeration step?

Comment: This is certainly possible, but an explicit formula will likely be very messy and inefficient, compared to say, an algorithm, or some recursive function. In any case, your best bet is probably to come up with a bijection like this for $\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{N}_0$, and see if it can be generalized to $\mathbb{Z}^3\to\mathbb{N}_0$.

Comment: why do you think it would be very messy? :)

Comment: Just my experience with bijections like these where we want extra properties like going out in layers. I once made a similar one for $\mathbb{N}_0\to\mathbb{N_0}^2$ and the formula was not simple, to say the least.